# Not able to pass variable in Firebase query-data

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As per the https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data I am trying to use below code in python and passing variable in the query.

Given example

```
docs = db.collection(u'cities').where(u'capital', u'==', True).get()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

I am trying to do as below by trying to substitute variable1 to compare its value and return the document id. The output dosen't return any response.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('/root/key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

variable1 = 9129392

docs = db.collection(u'company').where(u'companyid', u'==', variable1).get()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

Could someone please let me know how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: what is the value of `u`?

Answer (score 0):

In Firestore, check if `companyid` is a String or a Long (number).

Most people have stored it as a String - and if that's the case, variable1 will need to be declared as a string and have quotes in between:

```
variable1 = "9129392"
```

If you want it to be an Integer, make sure it is stored as a Number type in Firestore.